# g++ template name mangling

Tags: c++, templates, g++, inline-assembly, name-mangling

I need to use the address of a member of a template class in g++ inline assembly (as a compile-time constant value). Is it possible to express this? (I think that I need the mangled name of `T<U>::x`).

```
template < typename U >
struct T {
  static int x;
};

template < typename U >
void f () {
  asm ("somecommand T<U>::x");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using linux, you can use nm.

nm --demangle foo.o gives you the demangled names for your symbols
nm --no-demangle foo.o gives you the mangled names for your symbols.

Then you can compare the output of these 2 files to match up the mangled name to the demangled name.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `objdump` to extract the mangled name from an object which references it (you can use `c++filt` to go in the other direction but I know of no standalone program giving the mangled name; you could use the spec http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html and creates a mangler or do the mangling manually, but that's probably overkill).